# Why does appendChild change based on order of elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

https://jsfiddle.net/L835jsym/6/

I want to move to elements from one div to another using JavaScript. When I loop through and the divs they are moving TO is first it works. But when the div they are moving FROM is first it doesn't work. Why?

```js
const newButtonEls = document.getElementsByClassName("new-button");
for (let i = 0; i < newButtonEls.length; i++) {
  const container = document.getElementsByClassName('new-media-btn-container')[0];
  container.appendChild(newButtonEls[i]);
}
```

```html
<div class = "new-media-btn-container">
  <p>Should be inserted below</p>
</div>
<div class = "two">
  <p>Should not be inserted below here anymore</p>
  <button class = "new-button">New Audio</button>
  <button class = "new-button">New Folder</button>
</div>
```

```js
const newButtonEls = document.getElementsByClassName("new-button");
for (let i = 0; i < newButtonEls.length; i++) {
  const container = document.getElementsByClassName('new-media-btn-container')[0];
  container.appendChild(newButtonEls[i]);
}
```

```html
<div class = "two">
  <p>Should not be inserted below here anymore</p>
  <button class = "new-button">New Audio</button>
  <button class = "new-button">New Folder</button>
</div>
<div class = "new-media-btn-container">
  <p>Should be inserted below</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a **live** node list.

In the first example, when you move `New Audio` it is **still** the `0`th item in the collection because you moved it to earlier in the document.

In the second example, when you move `New Audio` to *later* in the document it becomes the `1`st element in the collection (you are changing the order of the elements that are members of that class) so when you increment `i` to `1` you append `New Audio` **again** and you never append `New Folder` (because you skipped over it when it was moved to position `0`).

You probably want to use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert the live node list into a static array.

Comment: Why doesn't `document.querySelector()` solve the problem?

Comment: Because it returns a single element (so you'd move just one element again but for a completely different reason).

Comment: I mean when defining container

Comment: Instead of `const container = document.getElementsByClassName('new-media-btn-container')[0];` doing `const container = document.querySelector('.new-media-btn-container');`

Comment: Because how you define the container *isn't* the problem

Comment: I am going to see if changing newButtonEls to querySelectorAll works